# Robotium - API Error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, robotium

I have just started using Robotium Recorder to automate android testing and  each time I try to record script an error is displayed. Below are the error details.

I have installed Robotium Recorder in Eclipse and created a test project. I have tried to record a test using Robotium Recorder but when I select New Robotium Test, following error is displayed even though respective API status is displayed as installed in SDK Manager.

[image]

[image]

[image]
Please note that I am using Eclipse Luna with version Luna SR1 (4.4.1), Robotium Recorder with version 2.1.17 and also using JAR file robotium-solo-5.0.1 for the test project.

[image]

Looking for any suggestion or help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Switch to *Latest Robotium* version **2.1.21**

Make sure that *`Used_Java.exe` present in Android SDK folder (Android\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe) is compatible with the version of Windows you're running*. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program.

If Used_Java.exe is compatible with the windows then also make sure that Android SDK which is not compatible with windows running in your system is not copied or present in the system even though it is not used by eclipse. If it is present in the system then remove it and restart the eclipse. Now you are able to record test through Robotium Recorder :)